# Sockets Queue Issue

Tags: c#, socketasynceventargs

hello all i have this issue , and i am stuck with it so any help will be greatly appreciated

i have to build a socket chat (client Server) module and i have done almost 80% of the work but now i am stuck , Scenario is that i have a server app and clients connect to it now if say 4 clients are connected to server each of them can communicate to each other , one client will send message and server will receive that message and will pass it along ,this is working very fine but when 2 or more  clients send a message to 3rd client at the same time than i can not get one message and client get disconnected i know i have to build up a queue structure but i am not getting succeeded in it here
here is my code structure

```
StartReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs) ->
```

First of all i call this method to start listening for incoming messages

and when i got one message i check if it is completed Sync or Async

and after this there is an io completed listener which is called every time one receive opertaion is completed and in that io completed method i do call processReceive method which is used to process received chunks 
so finally my code structure is like this

```
StartReceive-> IO Completed -> ProcessReceive
```

i have designed the structure so that every client will have a Receive SOCKETASYNCEVENTAGRS
object and a Send SOCKETASYNCEVENTAGRS at server side and i do maintain a pool for this

so each client receives and sends data through its own SOCKETASYNCEVENTAGRS object

i want a scenario such that if two or more clients send messages to 3rd client than 3rd client should not receive all messages at the same time instead it should have a queue structure and it should receive one message at a time and same for send operation

here is some of my code

```
  private void StartReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs receiveSendEventArgs)
    {
        DataHoldingUserToken receiveSendToken = (DataHoldingUserToken)receiveSendEventArgs.UserToken;
        receiveSendEventArgs.SetBuffer(receiveSendToken.bufferOffsetReceive, this.socketListenerSettings.BufferSize);                    
        bool willRaiseEvent = receiveSendEventArgs.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(receiveSendEventArgs);
        if (!willRaiseEvent)
        {

            ProcessReceive(receiveSendEventArgs);                
        }            
    }
```

This is IO Completed

```
 void IO_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        DataHoldingUserToken receiveSendToken = (DataHoldingUserToken)e.UserToken;
        switch (e.LastOperation)
        {
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:                
                ProcessReceive(e);
                break;

            default:
        }
    }
```

and this is my StartReceive with Queue implemented but it is not working

```
 Queue rec = new Queue();
    bool IsExecuted = true;
    private void StartReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs receiveSendEventArgs)
    {
        if (IsExecuted)
        {
            DataHoldingUserToken receiveSendToken = (DataHoldingUserToken)receiveSendEventArgs.UserToken;
            rec.Enqueue(receiveSendToken);
        }
        try
        {
            receiveSendEventArgs.SetBuffer(receiveSendToken.bufferOffsetReceive, this.socketListenerSettings.BufferSize);
            bool willRaiseEvent = receiveSendEventArgs.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(receiveSendEventArgs);
            if (!willRaiseEvent)
            {

                ProcessReceive(receiveSendEventArgs);
            }
            rec.Dequeue();
            IsExecuted = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            IsExecuted = false;
            StartReceive(receiveSendEventArgs);
        }
    }
```

looking for a decent help or some good direction

Comment: any help? i want it :(

Comment: If I get this whole thing right, you are passing information about the SAEA object as a UserToken to the same object. Why would you do that?

And a thing that is jumping at me is that you are using the System.Collections.Queue class instead of the recommended System.Collections.Generic.Queue<SocketAsyncEventArgs> class. If the rest of your class is working, maybe switching to the generic class would help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the root cause of your problem but it seems to me that you are running out of `DataHoldingUserToken` at some time because you are never doing anything with the objects you dequeue, hence you are throwing it away.

Also note that it is recommended to use the generic form of the Queue class for non-trivial object. That would be `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<DataHoldingUserToken>`.

Comment: thanks HAmster for your valuable time i was waiting for an answer and in mean while i re read my whole code and i figured out the problem , the real problem was with process receive method and i was processing other things in process receive part but it was messing things up so i removed the queue from process receive and now it is working to some extent and also u said that i am just throwing object after dequeue well i am working with these objects at process receive and thank you very much for you Suggestion of Generic Queue i wonder y i was not using this before i will go with it now:)